# Confusion over pointer index operator

Tags: c, pointers, operator-precedence

I am a little bit confused about pointer index operator in C. I will try to explain my question with an example:

```
int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *p;
p = array;
p[2]++;
```

In the fourth line, I know that it increments the second index of array. However, when I see an index operator, I convert it.

For instance, I converted `p[2]++` to `*(p+2)++`. According to the [operator precedence table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), in the statement of `*(p+2)++`, the increment and dereferencing operators have the same precedence, but increment takes precedence due to right associativity. Therefore, it becomes `*(p+3)`. Then, this statement cannot change any value and just points third index of  array.

Why does `p[2]++` increment the second index of the array? What is wrong in my perspective?

Comment: *I know that it increments the second index of array.*  No, it increments the ***third*** element of the array because the first element is at index `0`.

Comment: While `p[i]` and `*(p + i)` are equivalent, they are different operations using different separate operators and with different [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Besides, `x++` doesn't make sense if `x` is an rvalue (like `p + i` will be).

Comment: Your `*(p+2)++;` doesn't compile: please post *actual code* (`a` is undefined) but after correcting it to `array` and adding `*(p+2)++;` I get `error C2105: '++' needs l-value`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I take it that the OP *mentally* converted `p[2]++` to `*(p+2)++`.

Answer (score 4):

`p[2]++` is equivalent to `(*(p+2))++`, not `*(p+2)++`. You need an extra set of parentheses to maintain the precedence from the original expression.

Without them you've got `*(p+2)++` which, as you've noted, is equivalent to `*((p+2)++)`. This has a different meaning from the original expression since it splits up the `+2` and the `*`. They need to be done in the same step since `[2]` is a single atomic operation.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

As already commented p[2]++ can be converted to (*(p+2))++, because p[2] is the element you want to increment.
Think that when incrementing indexes is usually done like p[i++]

Answer (score 0):

In math, if `a=b+c`,then `a*d` is not `b+c*d` but `(b+c)*d`. Likely, `p[2]` is not be taken by `*(p+2)` but `(*(p+2))` to avoid any change on precedence.